# Do not close tooltip when input has focus after click

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

How can I make tooltip do not be closed if input has focus? It works when it gets focus with tab, but if I use mouse to focus on input, tooltip will be closed on `mouseout` even if input has focus.

I can do

```
$('input').tooltip().off("mouseover mouseout");
```

But this will dissable tooltip on hover and I just need to dissable `mouseout` when `input` has focus.

http://jsfiddle.net/3dX6d/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/3dX6d/3/

Comment: So you want the tooltip to appear (and stay appeared) when the input has focus? What about when you hover over input and it doesn't have focus? Do you want the standard tooltip? Or do you want the tooltip to only appear when element has focus?

Comment: hover should work, but `hoverout` should not close tooltip if element has focus.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX6d/4/)

```
$("input").tooltip({
    close: function (event, ui) { //when the tooltip is supposed to close 
        if ($('input').is(':focus')) { // check to see if input is focused 
            $('input').tooltip('open'); // if so stay open
        }
    }
});
```

**New and Improved Method:**

**[Better Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX6d/6/)**

```
$("input").tooltip({
    hide: {
        effect: 'explode'// added for visibility
    } 
}).mouseleave(function () { // on mouse leave
    if ($('input').is(':focus')) { // if input is focused 
        ui.tooltip.preventDefault(); //prevent the tooltip's default behavior
        $('input').tooltip('open'); // leave the tooltip open
    }
}).focusout(function () { // on focus out 
    $('input').tooltip('close'); // close the tooltip
});
```

API documentation:
[:focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)
[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
[.focusout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)
[open method](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-open)
[close event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-close)

Comment: It works, but it blinks (fast close and open) when mouse hover. I will use this if there is no other way.

Comment: The `ui.tooltip.preventDefault();` line appears to only work because it causes an error, which in turn prevents the tooltip from closing--obviously this might be undesirable.  The only simple way I've found to accomplish the same thing is `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` in its place.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding all these other listeners, I looked into the actual and decided the most effective way is to just inherit the widget and add an extra flag

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

Here's a demo
http://jsfiddle.net/3dX6d/7/

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("custom.tooltipX", $.ui.tooltip, {
        options: {
            focusPreventClose: false
        },

        close: function (event, target, content) {
            if (this.options.focusPreventClose && $(this.element).is(":focus")) {
                // Don't call the parent's close() call but therefore have to add event on focus out
                this._on({ focusout:this.close });
            } else {
                this._superApply(arguments);
            }
        }
    });
}(jQuery));

$('input').tooltipX({
    focusPreventClose: true
});
```

Compared to the other solution, this doesn't require us to do more work with the extra open calls (which actually does several other calls within it). We simply prevent the tooltip to close when we have the focus on the element, as requested by original post.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do to fix the ui error is just pass it in as a parameter per documentation.

http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#event-close

```
$(document).tooltip({ selector: "[title]" }).mouseleave(function(event, ui) {
    if ($('input').is(':focus')) {
        ui.tooltip.preventDefault();
        $('input').tooltip('open');
    }
});
```